# how to upload file to localhost

Tags: java, localhost

I'm trying to write a program to upload a specific file to the localhost.

Let us say if the file is (test.txt), the result should be `http://localhost:8080/hostProject/test.txt`.
I made a search and I found that commons `FileUpload` could help me but I'm not sure how to complete it. .

The program here is indpendent from the hostProject.

Comment: Are you trying to upload the file through a Web browser or through a standalone Java (maybe Swing) program?

Comment: sorry for this ambiguity. I'm trying to upload through a standalone swing java program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileUpload` is basically a special-purpose HTTP form handler, and it is useful for handling file uploads, but there are two other parts to this issue, your `hostProject` servlet and your client. Servlet 3.0 also includes some built-in multipart handling, so you might choose that route instead.

How you handle the servlet is entirely up to you. A few useful approaches are an all in-memory cache (easy but limited in size and won't persist between restarts), writing the files out to the filesystem and using something like Spring's `ResourceServlet` to serve them up just like any other on-disk file, or putting them in some data store (MongoDB, perhaps) and using the "file name" as a key to get them out again. Spring's [`MultipartResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart) may be helpful in building this.

In your client, you'll need to make a regular HTTP `POST` request, just like for any other HTTP interaction, and "attach" the uploaded file as a multipart entity.

Be aware that this functionality is a security risk (you don't want random people to be able to upload files that you serve), so you need to ensure that you have adequate security controls on your `FileUpload` servlet.

Answer (score 0):

You can chose the file using below code. You need to be clear what you want to do with the file afterwards :

```
JFileChooser c = new JFileChooser();
            int rVal = c.showOpenDialog(new JPanel());
            if (rVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                inputFile = c.getSelectedFile();
                System.out.println("File Selected : " + inputFile.getName());
            }
```

Comment: the problem here is not in choosing the file but in uploading it to the localhost. and I have to do the upload because the program I'm writing can only handle http links.

Answer (score 0):

You have to used a multi-part HTTP Form to upload a file.
Where you save it is up to your server side code, but personally I would not save it under your webapp.